# ExtractMsg.py checking for attachments and returning name

Tags: python, outlook

I am using a small script for reading a .msg file and printing the name of the attachment.  I know the email has an attachment but it only returns "None".  I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Can anyone help me?  The script is supposed to return the long filename based on information from the following link.  `print sender` prints the sender information fine, just always get a None for attachments

https://github.com/jbfuzier/msg-analyzer/blob/master/ExtractMsg.py

```
import ExtractMsg
import glob
for message in glob.glob('C:\Desktop\EMAILS\email_test\*.msg'):
    msg = ExtractMsg.Message(message)
    attach = msg._getStringStream('__substg1.0_3707')
    sender = msg._getStringStream('__substg1.0_0C1F')
    print attach
    print sender
```

Comment: what happens if you just do:

`for message in glob.glob('C:\Desktop\EMAILS\email_test\*.msg'):
    print(message)`

Comment: it prints the file location 'C:\Desktop\EMAILS\email_test\test.msg'

Comment: I have never used this, but it looks like it creates a new folder containing message and attachments when called, but your line `msg = ExtractMsg.Message(message)` is actually calling a function and storing this as an object. Have you tried `attach = message._getStringStream('_substg1.0_3707')` ? It is not clear to me if you are intended to call _getStringStream on the message itself or the file object.

Comment: trying that gets an error message  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_getStringStream'`